# Mpandroidchart Custom highlight at a Y axis value

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I want to highlight the Graph's Y axis using Custom drawable on MPChart - Android. Without tap event, I need to show this highlight.

So, i disabled the singletap for highlight like,

```
mChart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(false);
```

The code i tried is

```
MarkerImage myMarkerImage = new MarkerImage(getContext(), R.drawable.graph_circle_indicator);
mChart.setMarker(myMarkerImage);
```

But its not working.. Can anyone give me a headsup..